# Unexpected behavior of scale_x_datetime in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset with daily collected data.

```
R> toydata
                 date group coef
1 2011-11-04 23:59:59     1 2.32
2 2011-11-05 23:59:59     1 2.34
3 2011-11-06 23:59:59     1 2.46
4 2011-11-07 23:59:59     1 2.68
5 2011-11-04 23:59:59     2 2.17
6 2011-11-05 23:59:59     2 1.90
7 2011-11-06 23:59:59     2 2.13
8 2011-11-07 23:59:59     2 2.52
```

Everythings seems to work fine:

```
R> toydata$date
[1] "2011-11-04 23:59:59 EST" "2011-11-05 23:59:59 EST"
[3] "2011-11-06 23:59:59 EST" "2011-11-07 23:59:59 EST"
[5] "2011-11-04 23:59:59 EST" "2011-11-05 23:59:59 EST"
[7] "2011-11-06 23:59:59 EST" "2011-11-07 23:59:59 EST"
```

and

```
R> format(toydata$date, "%d-%b")
[1] "04-Nov" "05-Nov" "06-Nov" "07-Nov" "04-Nov" "05-Nov" "06-Nov" "07-Nov"
```

However, when I try to plot it using ggplot2 using the following code

```
R> p <- ggplot(toydata, aes(x = date, y = coef, group = group))
R> pq <- p + geom_line(aes(colour = group)) +
+   scale_x_datetime(major = "1 day", format = "%d-%b")
```

I get an unexpected result:

[image]

As you can see, November, 6 is duplicated. I can get around this problem by just treating the labels in x as strings and not as dates, but I am curious about why this is happening. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify `tz='EST'` and it works for me. Whatever the default is is repeating Nov 6 because of the daylight savings time switch.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just to clarify: `scale_x_datetime(major = "1 day", format = "%d-%b", tz = "EST")`

Comment: It might be worth checking at github to see if this is a bug that's been reported, and if not reporting it, just in case it's a fixable issue.

Comment: Yea...I'm always apprehensive to report date/time stuff because there are so many nuances and I'm def not an expert. I think the default here at some level might be to display in your own local time zone, in which case the repeated 06-Nov could actually be correct. I'm in 'America/Los_Angeles' so if I start with a sequence of EST times that are 24 hrs apart (i.e. what is probably used for the ticks) and that cross the daylight savings transition, and then format them in my local time, I get 06-Nov repeated as well. ...

Comment: For example, try: `format(as.POSIXct('2011-11-05 02:00:01 EST', tz='EST') + (0:4)*24*60*60, tz='America/Los_Angeles')`

Comment: I needed: scale_x_datetime(timezone='PST' ...  (not tz)