# POSIXct: as.POSIXct("2008-03-30 02:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") fails is it a bug in R?

Tags: r, statistics, posix, posixct, datetime-conversion

Very strange things happen while converting to POSIXct:

```
> as.POSIXct("2008-03-30 02:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

but:

```
> as.POSIXct("2008-02-28 02:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2008-02-28 02:00:00 CET"
```

I am clueless. is it a bug in R?
Does it perhaps have to do with my German (Berlin) locale?
I am using R 2.14.2 for windows.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("2008-03-30 02:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` returns `[1] "2008-03-30 02:00:00 BST"` on my console (R version 2.14.0). What context is this in?

Comment: It's probably DST in your locale, in which case 2AM doesn't exist.

Comment: yes alright so this is connencted Daylight saving time.  will go investigate how to make POSIXct parse it (and into what actually). thanks to everybody

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the beginning of daylight savings time in Germany in 2008, see this [link](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=37&year=2008). That time effectively is equivalent to "2008-03-30 03:00:00" (an hour later), which should work on your system. So, yes, this is related to your locale.

Comment: And now that you know what the problem is, you can search for "[r] 'daylight savings time'" on SO and find similar confusion abounding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455096/xtss-hourly-endpoints-and-daylight-savings , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408738/unexpected-behavior-of-scale-x-datetime-in-ggplot2 , and probably lots more on the R help lists ...